# How to extract the indeterminates from a set of polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-algebra-systems

I am a biologist and I am facing a huge problem. I would like to extract the indeterminates of a set of polynomials, for example, I have:

$f_{1} = \{\\x_{3}^{2} + x_{1}*x_{2} + x_{1} + x_{1}*x_{3},\\
x_{2}^{3}*x_{1}^{2} + x_{1}*x_{2}*x_{3} + x_{4}, \\ x_{2}^{2}+x_{4}+x_{4}^{3}+x_{2}+x_{2}*x_{4}\\
\}$

and I would like to have an automation of this process:

```
Process ("Extract the indeterminates of the set of polynomials fi)
```

$f_{1} = \{\\x_{3}^{2} + x_{1}*x_{2} + x_{1} + x_{1}*x_{3},\\
x_{2}^{3}*x_{1}^{2} + x_{1}*x_{2}*x_{3} + x_{4}, \\ x_{2}^{2}+x_{4}+x_{4}^{3}+x_{2}+x_{2}*x_{4}\\
\}$

```
Result
```

$f_{1, extracted} = \{\\(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}),\\
(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}), \\ 
(x_{2}, x_{4})\\
\}$

I have searched a method to do that in the documentations of Macaulay2, Magma, CoCoA and Mathematica but without success.

I hope you can help me! Without you, I will need to perform this manually (I have thousands of polynomials with different indeterminates combinations...). Thank you in advance!

Cheers,

Celina

Comment: There must be an easy solution, even my HP 50g has a command, namely LNAME, for that purpose.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on the appropriate programs' mailing lists or similar -- e.g. at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, this may be automated with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org). Consider the following GAP session:

1) Create polynomial ring with as much variables as you may need:

```
gap> R:=PolynomialRing(Rationals,5);
Rationals[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]
```

Remark: one can always add more indeterminates later, e.g.

```
gap> Indeterminate(Rationals,11);
x_11
```

(as you could see, numbers of indeterminates need not to be consecutive)

2) Get a list of indeterminates

```
gap> x:=IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R);
[ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 ]
```

to be able to address them by their position in the list `x`, for example

```
gap> x[4];
x_4
```

3) If you really need to parse the text where indeterminates are given using `x_i` notation, you could assign them programmatically, for example:

```
gap> for i in [1..Length(x)] do BindGlobal(Concatenation("x_",String(i)),x[i]);od;
```

Now the following works:

```
gap> x_1;
x_1
```

4) Finally, after previous steps, I have created all the necessary setup to be able to reproduce three polynomials from your example:

```
gap> f1:=x_3^2 + x_1*x_2 + x_1 + x_1*x_3;
x_1*x_2+x_1*x_3+x_3^2+x_1
gap> f2:=x_2^3*x_1^2 + x_1*x_2*x_3 + x_4;
x_1^2*x_2^3+x_1*x_2*x_3+x_4
gap> f3:=x_2^2+x_4+x_4^3+x_2+x_2*x_4;
x_4^3+x_2^2+x_2*x_4+x_2+x_4
```

5) The following function will calculate so called "external representation of a polynomial" as a list of the form `[mon,coeff,mon,coeff,...]` where `mon` is a monomial in expanded form (that is given as list) and `coeff` is its coefficient:

```
NumbersOfIndeterminates:=function(f)
local r, i, j, u;
u:=[];
r:=ExtRepPolynomialRatFun(f);
for i in [1,3..Length(r)-1] do
  for j in [1,3..Length(r[i])-1] do
    AddSet(u, r[i][j] );
  od;
od;
return u;
end;
```

I will just paste this code into GAP:

```
gap> NumbersOfIndeterminates:=function(f)
> local r, i, j, u;
> u:=[];
> r:=ExtRepPolynomialRatFun(f);
> for i in [1,3..Length(r)-1] do
>   for j in [1,3..Length(r[i])-1] do
>     AddSet(u, r[i][j] );
>   od;
> od;
> return u;
> end;
function( f ) ... end
```

6) Now I am able to use it as intended:

```
gap> NumbersOfIndeterminates(f1);
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
gap> NumbersOfIndeterminates(f2);
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
gap> NumbersOfIndeterminates(f3);
[ 2, 4 ]
gap> NumbersOfIndeterminates(Zero(R));
[  ]
gap> NumbersOfIndeterminates(Sum(x));
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Some final remarks: I'd be interested to know in which form do you have the input data and do you have control over the syntax there. Do you have them as a text file? Can you just generate an input file for GAP? Are you able e.g. to change its format to use `x[1]` instead of `x_1`, etc.? Is there one line per polynomial in the text file or not? If not, how they are separated?

It is certainly possible to organise that GAP will read the text file line by line, parse and evaluate polynomials. It may also happen that one could the same without using any computer algebra system, just with a help of some shell script.

**Update**: For example, GAP could read this (some preliminary setup would be needed to define list `f:=[];` and all inderteminates):

```
f[1]:=[
x2−x4−1,
x2+x1+1,
x3+1,
];

f[2]:=[
−x2−x3−1,
x2+x4+1,
x3*x2−x4,
x2−x1−1,
x3+x1−1,
];
```

Line breaks and empty lines does not matter, as well as commas after the last element of the list.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. My data are in text files and I can generate an input file for GAP (I can change x_i into x[i], the separators, etc.) and there is not really one line per polynomial. This is a small example:$\\
f1 = \{\\
x2-x4-1 \\  
x2+x1+1 \\  
x3+1  \\ 
\}\\
f2 = \{\\
-x2-x3-1 \\  
x2+x4+1  \\ 
x3-x4  \\ 
x2-x1-1 \\  
x3+x1-1  \\ 
\}\\
\\$ Thus, there are two sets of polynomials. Do you think that GAP can handle this kind of format or do I need to separate each set in this way $\\
f1.1=\\
...\\
f1.3=\\
f2.1=\\
...\\
f2.5=\\$
in a unique text file? (Sorry for the ugly layout)

Comment: @Celina: thanks - I've updated my answer to show an example of what GAP will parse easily. That's very close to your input, hopefully adding separators like commas and brackets is an easy task. I suggest to have a list of sets, so you may address its elements by index like `f[n]`, not `fn`.

Comment: @Celina: P.S.: do you need to do any post-processing of lists of indeterminates involved in polynomials and their sets? GAP may help here as well, see e.g. the [GAP Manual chapter on lists](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap21.html)

Comment: Very nice my Professor. :)